# Architectural tips on building a shared resource for different processess

Tags: c++, linux, architecture

In the company I work at we're dealing with a huge problem: we have a system that consists in several units of processing. We made it this way so each module has specific functionality. The integration between these modules is done using a queue system (which is not fast but we're working on it) and replicating messages between these modules. The problem is that this is generating a great deal of overhead as four of these systems are requiring the same kind of data, and maintaining consistency for these modules is bad.

Another requirement for the system is redundancy, so I was thinking to kill these two problems in one shot.

So I was thinking of using some kind of shared resource. I've looked at shared memories (which are great but could lead to locking inconsistencies if the [module crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070723/locking-mechanisms-for-shared-memory-consistency) leading to inconsistencies in the program), and maybe do some "raw copy" from the segment to another computer to do redundancy.

So I've began to search for alternatives, ideas and something like that. I've found one that is noSQL, but I don't know if the speed that I'm requiring would suffice this.

I need something (ideally):

- Memory-like fast
- That could provide me redundancy (active-passive is ok, active active is good)

Comment: Are you putting this all on a single machine?  If not, you're not getting "memory-like fast"

Comment: The shared memory part is on the same machine. The redundant part is on separate machine(s). So, besides the copy part everything should work as local memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think that shared-memory is the way to go.  To provide redundancy, let every process copy the data that is going to be changed to local/non-shared memory.  Only after the module has done its work, copy it back to shared memory.  Make sure the 'copy-to-shared-memory' part is as small as possible and nothing can go wrong while doing the copy.  Some tricks you could use are:

- Prepare all data in local memory and use one memcpy operation to copy it to shared memory
- Use a single value to indicate that the written data is valid.  This could be a boolean or something like a version number that indicates the 'version' of the data written in shared memory.